# Download Blob file with php ( mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, file, blob

I have a MySQL database where I have a table call for example "ALL" can contain a blob files.

In the table i have stored the: size of the file, the type, the name and the content.

The problem come when i try download the blob file.

This is my script:

```
<?php
$connection =  mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password",dbname)
or die('Database Connection Failed');
mysqli_set_charset($connection,'utf-8');

$query = "SELECT * " ."FROM ALL WHERE id = '25'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) 
or die('Error, query failed');

 list($id, $user_made, $title, $category, $sub_category, $text, $type, $date, $time, $namefile1, $typefile1, $sizefile1, $contentfile1, $namefile2, $typefile2, $sizefile2, $contentfile2, $namefile3, $typefile3, $sizefile3, $contentfile3) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo $id . $namefile1 . $typefile1 . $sizefile1;
 header('Content-Length: '.$sizefile1);
 header('Content-Type: '.$typefile1);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$namefile1.'"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');  
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 // echo $contentfile1;
 mysqli_close($connection);
 exit;
?>
```

But the page output only the echo of "$contentfile1" and "$id . $namefile1 . $typefile1 . $sizefile1".

Everyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: You need echo content of file, not id or other information. Other data you need to set into headers, like file-size (content-length), file-type, file-name & etc

Comment: Thank Aleksey, i have solve my problem! Thank again

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read images from MySQL database using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770834/how-to-read-images-from-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before ob_clean.

```
    $context = stream_context_create();
    $file = fopen($filename, 'rb', FALSE, $context);
    while(!feof($file))
    {
       echo stream_get_contents($file, max_bytes_to_read);
    }
    fclose($file);
```

You can get more information about stream_get_contents at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php